# Django save dict from Json to DB

Tags: python, json, django

i would like to know how i can save a field i get from json as dict. to my database field.
Currently i only get

> 'int' object is not callable

thank and regards

Comment: Please add the full model and view and the full error traceback.

Comment: i added the field from models.py
The rest is a snipped from a celery job so no views or templates only pure data processing.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `user.acc_balance('confirmed')`? As the error says, `acc_balance` is an integer, it does not know what to do with the 'confirmed' param that you are passing.

Comment: yes i guess this is my mistake i simply want to save the vaule of "confirmed" to the DB field "user.acc_balance" nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: What's with the `update_or_create` part? Do you want to save the data in the user that you have as `user`? If i understand correctly what you want is to save the confirmed value from decoded_balance to the user's acc_balance field. Is that correct?

Comment: 100% correct interpretation!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
decoded_balance = json.loads(check_balance) 
user.acc_balance = decoded_balance["confirmed"]
user.save()
```

You already have the `user`, just update it's `acc_balance` field and save it.

Also, you might want to check how to [parse json](https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/json/#parsing-json). For example, in this case you have something like this:

```
decoded_balance
# eg: {'confirmed': 2, 'unconfirmed': 3}
decoded_balance["confirmed"]
# 2
```

Comment: okay and what if the value of confirmed changes from time to time or increases?
thx so far :D

Comment: i don't know the larger scope of your code, but if you already have the user in a variable as in this case, you are updating the acc_balance field by assigning a new value and saving it. You would use update_or_create if you don't know for sure that the user exists, also you would need to pass all the other fields necessary to get or create a correct user, not just the acc_balance